# Join two pandas dataframe columns row-wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming I have a pandas dataframe `df`, whereby df is:

```
    vaccine       age           height
0   pfizer       48.0            181.0
1   moderna      81.0            175.0
2   moderna      27.0            190.4
3   moderna      64.0            178.5
```

I am trying to join the two columns (age, height) into a single column row-wise, whereby age and height are grouped by their respective vaccine.

Basically, I am trying to get:

```
   vaccine        new_col     
0   pfizer         48.0
1   pfizer         181.0
2   moderna        81.0         
3   moderna        175.0
4   moderna         27.0             
5   moderna        190.4
6   moderna         64.0
7   moderna        178.5
```

I have unsuccessfully tried using pd.concat, df.merge, etc. I am not familiar with any pandas function that does this. I also tried using the apply function but I wasn't successful.

Comment: `df.set_index("vaccine").stack()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the index as `vaccine` then `stack` the dataframe, and drop index level at 1, finally reset the index.

```py
df.set_index('vaccine').stack().droplevel(1).to_frame('new_col').reset_index()

   vaccine  new_col
0   pfizer     48.0
1   pfizer    181.0
2  moderna     81.0
3  moderna    175.0
4  moderna     27.0
5  moderna    190.4
6  moderna     64.0
7  moderna    178.5
```